# Find multiple lines spanning text and replace using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using a regular expression search to match up and replace some text. The text can span multiple lines (may or may not have line breaks).
Currently I have this:

```
 $regex = "\<\?php eval.*?\>"

Get-ChildItem -exclude *.bak | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} |ForEach-Object {
 $text = [string]::Join("`n", (Get-Content $_))
 $text -replace $RegEx ,"REPLACED"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$regex = New-Object Text.RegularExpressions.Regex "\<\?php eval.*?\>", ('singleline', 'multiline')

Get-ChildItem -exclude *.bak |
  Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} |
  ForEach-Object {
     $text = (Get-Content $_.FullName) -join "`n"
     $regex.Replace($text, "REPLACED")
  }
```

A regular expression is explicitly created via [New-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849885.aspx) so that options can be passed in.

Comment: I think you want `Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}` and that it is definitely a better way to go IMO (vs testing the Attributes).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your regex pattern to:

```
 "(?s)\<\?php eval.*?\>"
```

to get singleline (dot matches any char including line terminators).  Since you aren't using the `^` or `$` metacharacters I don't think you need to specify multiline (`^` & `$` match embedded line terminators).

*Update:* It seems that -replace makes sure the regex is case-insensitive so the `i` option isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

One should use the `(.|\n)+` expression to cross line boundaries 
since `.` doesn't match new lines.